# finding the index of the start of the last repeating sequence in the list

Tags: python, loops, indexing, while-loop, duplicates

e.g.the index of first element of the last repeating in list [2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1] would be 5

How do I solve this WITHOUT using the builtin index() function?

```
def get_index_of_last_repeating_sequence(l:list[int]):
    index =0
    
    while l[index] != l[index-1]:
        index+=1
        
....
            
    return index-1
```

I get stuck on making an inner loop and how to terminate it to go back to the outer loop

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by iterating over list backwards and finding the first sequence of repeated items.

```
def get_index_of_last_repeating_sequence(lst: list[int]):
    repeated = None
    kk =  len(lst) - 1
    while kk >= 1:
        if lst[kk] == lst[kk - 1]:
            repeated = lst[kk]
        if repeated is not None and repeated != lst[kk-1]:
            return kk
        kk -= 1
    if repeated is not None:
        return 0
    return -1
```

---

```
>>> get_index_of_last_repeating_sequence([0,1,2,5,5,5,4])
3
>>> get_index_of_last_repeating_sequence([0,1,2,3,4,5])
-1
>>> get_index_of_last_repeating_sequence([1,1,2,3,4,5])
0
```

Comment: Try it for [1,1,2,3,4,5], expected to return **0** (start of 1,1 sequence), but it returns **-1**!!

Comment: yep. Added handling for this edge case